# Can I talk to the blue alpaca?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Reese's boyfriend seems to constantly be asleep. When I try and talk to him, she warns me that he's been hard at work all night, but I can't actually enter the shop at night.

Is there any way to talk to him or any benefit for doing so? I've tried to talk to him daily for a week (thinking it was something akin to talking to Sable) but I've had no luck. Trying to come in after-hours doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Prima Guide, you have to spent "a lot of money" at Re-Tail before he will wake up during the day. Once he does, though,

> He will be able to help you customize your furniture. He can also take a complete dinosaur skeleton set and make it into a miniature model

According to the [Animal Crossing wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Cyrus), which gives more detail about the specifics than the guide does,

> Cyrus will awaken and provide his services only with the gate closed and no visitors. To use him, four conditions must be met:
>
> - 100,000 Bells worth of items have been sold to Reese.
> - 50 pieces of furniture have been cataloged (found at the Nookling Stores).
> - 10 pieces of clothing cataloged (from the Able Sisters).
> - The player has played for seven days.

Comment: I have had Cyrus unlocked for a while, and I barely have 100 furniture items in my catalog. http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/66514945 sites much lower requirements, but it's a message board.

Comment: Your link actually says the same thing now: 50 furniture, 10 clothes.

Answer (score 2):

> Cyrus the blue alpaca is the town's Upholsterer. He is in the thrift store with Reese, and is her husband. This is where you go to have custom furniture changes made. There are a few hundred items that can be changed. Examples of changes: colours, types of wood and your own designs. Other examples: Lamps can be changed to different colors (red / orange / yellow / green / blue / purple) for a small fee. You can even customize some furniture series using ore.

[Source](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Re-Tail)

> Cyrus will be asleep for awhile after your player is created. He wakes up when your catalog has reached at least 50 furniture items, your catalog has at least 10 tops, and you have at least 100,000 bells in transactions with Reese.

Answer (score 0):

> When certain furniture is brought to Cyrus, he may offer to paint it and give a list of shades it can be painted. Usually this is one shade lighter, one shade darker and one different shade that can be related to the other colors. Furniture that has been painted will show up as a red leaf instead of a green leaf. The prices vary, but are usually priced around 200 bells.

[Source - Nookipedia](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Cyrus)

> For the first 7 days in town, Cyrus will be asleep at his desk, unavailable. According to Reese, Cyrus worked on a project all night and is "extremely tired". After the player has sold 100,000 Bells worth of items, along with having acquired 100 pieces of furniture and 50 pieces of clothing in their catalog, Cyrus's customization services will be available.

[image: Cyrus]