# I woke up Cyrus, but he went back to sleep

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing: New Leaf, I woke up Cyrus. But then he went back to sleep! HELP! I went into the shop, and he had woken up! But when I came back, he was sleeping again :(
Is something wrong with my game?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Do you need to know how to wake him up?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stretch, but I had something similar happen in my game as well.

Cyrus is awake on my main character, but when I switched over to a different character in the same town, Cyrus appears to be asleep again.  Switching back to my main shows him awake once more.

I've tried this again, after having Cyrus work on customizing a peice of furniture on my main character.  Swtiching over to the sub shows him sleeping on the job again, and the project not on the table.

I would believe this is a case of **[Can I talk to the blue alpaca](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120447/can-i-talk-to-the-blue-alpaca)**, with the point that Cyrus will only be awake per character that reaches said milestone.  Anyone new to the town (or who has yet to reach the requirements) will only get to see Cyrus sleeping the day away.

---

EDIT: To note, the question is "why Cyrus asleep even after waking him up", It's presumed that the player has already unlocked Cyrus, but might be playing on a second character in the same town.

Comment: Welcome! :) Make sure to select "Answered" so it's easier for others to follow up!